# Input boxes with different styles on the same page

Tags: html, css

I have the following style for an input box

```css
input[type="text"] { 
  height: 16px ; 
  font-size: 14 ;
  border-radius: 5px ;  
}
```

What I want to do is have this style on most of the inputs but I want to make a class of input so I can add background color, etc. How can I do this in the style sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes

Define a class with the different style and apply it to the input element in the HTML:

```css
input[type="text"] { 
  height: 16px ; 
  font-size: 14 ;
  border-radius: 5px ;  
}

input[type="text"].different {
  background-color: #d6eaf8;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="different" />
```

---

This input will have all the properties of the generic rule `input[type="text"]` and then apply all the properties of `input[type="text"].different` class.

The `input[type="text"].different` is more important so in case of overlapping properties the ones in the `.different` class will prevail.

---

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Class_selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type="text"].yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I would caution against this approach (naming the class after the characteristic); it is an [tag:anti-patterns] because it tightly couples the style to the content. If you ever decide to change the formatting, you will have to edit the HTML (defeating the purpose of CSS), or make your "yellow" CSS class do something confusing, like `background-color:red`.